# PHP script to modify a dynamic website link and open a new tab

Tags: php, ubuntu, lamp

This is my first question so if I am doing something wrong just let me know.
I currently maintain a webserver running `ubuntu`, `php` and `mysql`.

What I would like to do is add a new page to the site which shows a user a box where they can input text and when they click "Go" it modifies a URL and opens a new tab.

For example the URL would look like the below.

```
http://1.2.4.5/api.php?getServices={"account":"variable"}
```

If the person was to input `12345` into the box and select Go it would modify the link to:

```
http://1.2.4.5/api.php?getServices={"account":"12345"}
```

I have attempted multiple different ways to implement this but had no luck so far and I can't seem to find any information about it online, could anyone give me a hand?

Comment: Php can't modify a URL and open a new tab. It is a browser specification and should be deal with javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JavaScript for this as:

```
$(document).on('click', '#buttonid', function(){
    var variable_name = $('#textboxid').val();
    var url = 'http://1.2.4.5/api.php?getServices={"account":"'+variable_name+'"}';
    window.open(url);
});
```

Or you can do it using PHP too. Add `target="_blank"` attribute in your `<form>` tag

```
<form action="action.php" target="_blank" method="post">
```

And then write this PHP script on action.php

```
$url = 'http://1.2.4.5/api.php?getServices={"account":"'.$_POST['variable_name'].'"}';
header('location: '.$url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use AJAX for that, and javascript for new tab.
PHP is executed server side, you can't do it with